# String to yy format of year in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, datetime, razor

I want to format year to this format yy = 17 i tried with this code but not working it is wrong format .

```
<select id="CreditCardExpiryDateYear" class="dropdown form-control">
       @for (var iYear = DateTime.Now.Year; iYear <= DateTime.Now.Year + 10; iYear++)
          {
           <option value="@iYear.ToString("yy")" @(DateTime.Now.Year == iYear ? " selected" : "")>@iYear.ToString("yy")</option>
          }
</select>
```

Comment: `@((iYear%100).ToString("00"))`

Comment: iYear is an `int` and not `DateTime` use it as an `int`

Answer (score 3):

The format applies to the type `DateTime`, not the Year property which is `int`.
Either use `DateTime.Now.ToString("yy")`, or `iYear % 100`

Answer (score 0):

Why not do like this -

```
(iYear% 100)
```